# Laravel and PJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pjax

I can't for the life of me get Pjax to work with Laravel. I've tried everything but the blade templating is screwing it up. When I don't use the blade templating I can get it to work.

What happens is that the AJAX page loads and then unfortunately, there is a redirect to the same exact URL. So the page loads twice.

I have no idea how to modify the blade templating engine to accomodate Pjax and suppress this 2nd page load. Anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original poster here. This multiple loading issue is caused by Homestead/vagrant being slow. If you set the `timeout` option on PJAX to `3500` (ms) then you won't encounter this issue.

And for those concerned that 3.5 second page loading is slow and renders PJAX useless, note that on a production server, even an EC2 microinstance, your Laravel app loading time will be 1/10th what it is on Vagrant so you'll be in the `350`ms range and will have no problem using PJAX with its default `650`ms timeout.

Answer (score 3):

How are you extending your layouts? You essentially need two layouts to get PJAX working properly - one with all your scripts and whatnot, and another that just displays your requested view.

**app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```php
public function boot() {
    view()->share('layout', 'layouts.main');
}
```

**app/Middleware/PjaxCheck.php**

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->pjax())
    {
        view()->share('layout', 'layouts.pjax');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

(don't forget to add that to your `Kernel`)

**resources/views/layouts/main.blade.php**

```html
<html>
    <body>
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

**resources/views/layouts/pjax.blade.php**

```html
@yield('content')
```

**View**

```html
@extends($layout)
@section('content')
    Some html content
@endsection
```

---

Essentially in `AppServiceProvider` you're telling every view that the `$layout` var should default to `layouts.main`. In the Pjax Middleware, you then overwrite that variable with `layouts.pjax` instead.

Comment: Really great answer @Alex. The problem I'm having revolves around the default pjax response timeout of `650ms`. With Codeigniter I never hit up against that response timeout, but sadly with Laravel for most of my app's links I do. The app isn't do anything special just accessing a DB like many other apps so not sure what can be done. Extending the timeout to `3000ms` does solve the problem but that defeats the purpose of PJAX.

Comment: That seems a bit...off! Have you tried profiling your app with something like [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to find out where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: Here's my profile: `Booting (493.21ms), Application (561.17ms), After application (26.3ms)`. Seems kinda long, right?

Comment: Very. On a fresh install; `Booting (64.74ms), Application (5.3ms), After application (1.68ms)`
Use `Debugbar::startMeasure()` and `::stopMeasure()` to profile certain parts of your app (like loading providers in `AppServiceProvider`, etc) to try and find the bottleneck(s)

Comment: Thanks @Alex! Exactly what I was looking for. I did it similarly for years in Smarty but now I'm learning Laravel+Blade, so your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container',{
    timeout : 10000,
    fragment : ".root"
});
```

**timeout**  : ajax timeout in milliseconds after which a full refresh is forced

**fragment** : CSS selector for the fragment to extract from ajax response